# php variable = variable1 || variable2

Tags: php, variables

Is this possible?

```
php $variable = $variable1 || $variable2?
```

if $variable1 is empty use $variable2

Is there existing that is something like that?

Comment: Just try or read documentation. It's impossible because all boolean operations in PHP always returns boolean value.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

PHP 5.3+:

```
$variable = $variable1 ?: $variable2;
```

PHP 5.2-:

```
$variable = $variable1 ? $variable1 : $variable2;
```

Comment: Note it wont work for testing if variables are set. You still need the long form, i.e. `isset($variable1) ? $variable1 : $variable2`.

Comment: which is a good thing, as it prevents potential unnoticed problems arising from typos or refactoring..

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, the `||` operator returns a boolean, it isn't a short circuit operator as it is in Perl or JavaScript, so you can't use that syntax.

You could use a [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

```
$variable = $variable1 ? $variable1 : $variable2
```