# PHP is there anyway to do this javascript trick?

Tags: php, variables, ternary-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php variable = variable1 || variable2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11954422/php-variable-variable1-variable2)

Trying to do this in PHP evaluates to true, instead of returning 'nothing' like js does.

```
//Javascript
var stuff = false;
document.write(stuff || 'nothing');
```

So I have to do this. Is there anyway to avoid typing the variable `stuff` twice?

```
//PHP
$stuff = false;
echo !empty($stuff)?$stuff:'nothing';
```

Comment: Yea, it's a hard question to phrase. I couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use PHP 5.3 or later you can use the shorthand ternary format:

```
echo ($stuff) ?: 'nothing';
```